# Преобразование заданных типов

Tags: golang

В начале кода пишу:

```
type UserId uint16
```

Затем, где-то понадобилось использовать переменную типа `UserId` как строку. Как правильно преобразовать значение? `string()` преобразовывает переменную в нечитаемый символ, а [`strconv.Itoa`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Atoi) выдает ошибку

> cannot use id (type CategoryId) as type int in function argument

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, это дико обходной путь, но это первое, что пришло в голову:

```golang
type UserID uint16
var x UserID = 42

fmt.Sprintf("%d", x) // возвращает строку
//           ^^ форматировать как десятичное число
```

...и, разумеется, можно сделать явное преобразование обратно в число:

```
strconv.FormatUint(uint64(x), 10)
```

Только **убедитесь**, что с типом в процессе всех этих преобразований **ничего не теряется**.

Answer (score 1):

```
type UserID uint16
var user_id UserID = 42

//Возможна потеря значений из-за разрядности
var _ string = strconv.Itoa( int(user_id) )

// Itoa это просто сокращенное написание FormatInt(int64(i), 10).
//  func Itoa(i int) string {
//      return FormatInt(int64(i), 10)
//  }

// Так что пользуемся FormatUint для беззнаковых
var _ string = strconv.FormatUint( uint64(user_id), 10)
```